# i want to alter a specific textbox with type=number

Tags: php, html, css

i already used the following codes

```html
input[type=number]{
    width:312px;
}
```

but it affected all the textboxes.I only want to alter 1 textbox. how would i do that? thank you!

Comment: Show us your HTML and indicate which text box should be affected.

Comment: You can use `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your input value an ID like this.

```
<input type="number" id="number-input" />
```

Then you can style it like this

```
#number-input {
    width:312px;
}
```

Giving your HTML an ID or Class makes it possible to style those HTML elements different from the other same elements. (e.g. `<span class="test"></span>` can be styled differently then `<span></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Example using CSS `class` and `id`

```css
/* This applies to element with class="wide" */
.wide {
  width: 312px;
}

/* This applies to element with id="wide" */
#wide {
  width: 312px;
}
```

```html
<input class="wide" type="number" name="quantity" />
<br>
<input type="number" name="quantity" />
<br>
<input type="number" name="quantity" />
<br>
<input id="wide" type="number" name="quantity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your HTML looks like, there are many options to consider :

```css
input[type=number] {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
} 

#first {
    width:312px;
} 

.second {
    width:312px;
} 

[data-special=third] {
    width:312px;
} 

.second input[type=number] {
    width:312px;
}
```

```html
<input type=number id="first" />

<input type=number class="second" />

<input type=number data-special="third" />

<div class="second"><input type=number /></div>
```